# if statement checking that div hasClass

Tags: jquery

hi i want to write if statement which is checking if div dont hasClass and if dont has it script should add it using toggleClass (i'm useing jquery ui), i wrote script above whitch is working almost fine but the first (this) should point to (.apla) that has not "min" class and the second (this) should point (.apla) with clicked (.arrow)

point of this is to check if any (.apla) is open and if any (.apla) is open script should close it using toggleClass (with animation), and after this script should open clicked (.apla) also using toggleClass, could u help me pls

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/eNqew/

JS

```
$('.arrow').click(function(){
    if (!$(".apla").hasClass("min")) {
    $(this).toggleClass("min", "slow");
    } else {
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("min", "slow");
    }
});
```

UPDATE JS works almost

```
$('.arrow').click(function(){
        if (!$("#apla01").hasClass("min")) {
            $("#apla01").toggleClass("min", "slow");
        }
        if (!$("#apla02").hasClass("min")) {
            $("#apla02").toggleClass("min", "slow");
        }
        if (!$("#apla03").hasClass("min")) {
            $("#apla03").toggleClass("min", "slow");
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("min", "slow");
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="apla01" class="apla min">
    <div class="apla-wraper">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>      
</div>
<div id="apla02" class="apla min">
    <div class="apla-wraper">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>      
</div>
<div id="apla03" class="apla min">
    <div class="apla-wraper">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

CSS

```
#apla01.apla.min {
    z-index: 5;
    left: -800px;
}
#apla02.apla.min {
    z-index: 4;
    left: -760px;
}
#apla03.apla.min  {
    z-index: 3;
    left: -720px;
}
.apla {
    width: 838px;
    height: 634px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    background: url(../img/bgApla.png) no-repeat -5px center;
}
.apla.min {
}
.apla-wraper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.arrow {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: -10px;
    margin-top: -14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.apla.min  .arrow{
    background: url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat -28px 0;
}
```

Comment: But you find the related container alpa: `$(this).closest(".apla").hasClass("min")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('.arrow').click(function(){
    var $currentApla = $(this).parent().parent()
    $('.apla:not(.min)').not('#'+$currentApla.attr('id')).toggleClass("min", "slow");
    $currentApla.toggleClass("min", "slow")
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: @gidzior - I have tried this new version in yout jsFidle and it seems to work

Answer (score 1):

This chek the parent .alpa class:

```
    $('.arrow').click(function(){
         $('.apla').not('.min').not($(this)).toggleClass("min", "slow");
         $(this).closest(".apla").toggleClass("min", "slow");
    });
```

Comment: @gidzior could you try to replicate your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), I'm not sure to correctly understend what happen.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be after `.is()` as it returns true or false

```
 $('.arrow').click(function(){
     if (!$(".apla").is(".min")) {
     $(this).toggleClass("min", "slow");
     } else {
     $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("min", "slow");
     }
 });
```

Comment: wow, i missed a trick there then :| i thought you watned to check if .apla has a class of .min lol whoops